# How to get Query Parameter in Spring with Vaadin?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, servlets, vaadin

I am trying to get a query Paramter from my url. The url looks like this:

`http://localhost:1001/login?continue=/teams`

When I try to get the continue param I get null.

```
request.getParameter("continue")
```

returns null so I tried to read the whole Query String but

```
request.getQueryString()
```

returns only this:

`v-r=uidl&v-uiId=1`

How can I access my query Params?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you don't want to use Spring MVC you can refer to this example:

https://vaadin.com/directory/component/url-parameter-mapping

There are some out of the box annotation Vaadin side, which can be helpful for your purpose.

Seems like you can use `@UrlParameter` both in method level and as a class member.
so you can have a wider scope if your application requires it.

Answer (score 1):

Spring gives you the capability to use @RequestMapping and @RequestParam in order to get those.

example: http://localhost:8080/spring-rest/ex/bars?id=100

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/ex/bars", method = GET)
@ResponseBody
public String getBarBySimplePathWithRequestParam(
  @RequestParam("id") long id) {
    return "Get a specific Bar with id=" + id;
}
```

In your case you will have to add @RequestParam("continue") annotation.

You can ignore for now @RequestBody annotation, but make sure your controller is annotated with @RequestMapping and as argument of your method you have the @RequestParam..

I took this example in the following site: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-requestmapping

There are other interesting things in it

Comment: I have the problem that I need to call the method myself because of Vaadin. I can not use RequestMapping. Is there another possibility to achieve this?

Comment: You can use Spring MVC with Vaadin, however if in your specific case you can not I found there are some annotations that you can use (out of the box of vaadin) I am sharing the link in this comment: https://vaadin.com/directory/component/url-parameter-mapping

Answer (score 1):

`v-r=uidl&v-uiId=1` indicates that the request that you're looking at is an internal XHR request sent by Vaadin's automatic communication layer.

See https://vaadin.com/docs/v12/flow/routing/tutorial-router-url-parameters.html#query-parameters for details on how to access the query parameters from the URL that it shown in the browser address bar.